# Overloading operator in Node class

Tags: c++, linked-list, overloading

I need to overload the ++ operator in my Node class so that when I call it, It returns the pointer of the next node. As well as a -- one that returns the previous one. I'm not familiar with overloading operators at all, so I'm pretty lost on how to go about it. I think i've got the syntax somewhat correct, but am unsure how to implement it. Do I make a member function with it? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

My Node class:

```
#ifndef NODE_H
#define NODE_H
class Node
{
public:
    Node(Node* n = NULL, int v =0)
    {
        next = n;
        value = v;
    }

    LinkedList& operator++(const LinkedList )

    Node* next;
    Node* prev; 
    int value;
};

#endif
```

Not sure if it helps, but here is my `LinkedList` file:

```
#ifndef LinkedList_H
#define LinkedList_H
#include "Node.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
class LinkedList{

public:
    LinkedList()
    {
        front = NULL;
        back = NULL;
        size = 0;
    }

    void push_front(int item)
    {
        if (front == NULL)
        {
            front = new Node(NULL, item);
            back = front;
            size++;
            return; 
        }

        Node* newNode = new Node(NULL, item);
        front->prev = newNode;
        newNode->next = front;
        front = newNode;
        size++;
    }

    int pop_front()
    {
        if (front == NULL){
            cout<<"No item to pop "<<endl;
            return 0;
        }

        Node *temp = front;
        int value = front->value;
        if(front->next){
            front = front->next;
            front->prev = NULL;
            size--;
            delete temp;
            return value;
        }

        front = NULL;
        back = NULL;
        return value; 
    }

    int pop_back()
    {
        if(front == NULL){
            cout<<"Nothing to pop! ";
            return 0;
        }
        else{
            Node *prev = front;
            Node *succ = front->next;
            while(succ->next != NULL){
                succ = succ->next;
                prev = prev->next;
            }
            int value = succ->value;
            prev->next = NULL;
            back = prev;

            delete succ;
            size--;
            return value;
        }
    }

    void push_back(int item)
    {
        if (front == NULL)
        {
            front = new Node(NULL, item);
            size++;
            return; 
        }
        else {

            Node* newnode = new Node(NULL, item);
            Node *succ = front;
            while(succ->next != NULL){
                succ = succ->next;
            }
            succ->next = newnode;
            newnode->next = NULL;
            newnode->prev = succ;
            back = newnode;
            size++;
        }
    }

    void print()
    {   
            if (front == NULL){
            cout<<"Nothing to print! "<<endl;
        }

        Node *p = front;
        while(p){
            cout<<p->value<<"  ";
            p=p->next;
        }

        cout<<endl<<endl;
    }

    bool removeNode(int i){

        if (i < 0 || i >= size) //assume size is a data member of double linked 
            return false;
        if (front == NULL)
            return false;
        if (i == 0)
        {
            Node* p = front; //assume front is a data member of double linked list
            front = front->next;
            front-> prev = NULL;
            delete p;
            size--;
            if (size == 1)
                back = front;
            return true;
        }

        int temp=0;
        Node* curr = front;
        Node* p = NULL;
        while (temp!= (i-1) && curr->next !=NULL)
        {
            p = curr;
            curr = curr->next;
            temp++;
        }

        p->next = curr->next;
        curr->next->prev = p;
        delete curr;
        size--;
        if (size == 1)
            back = front;
        return true;
    }

    LinkedList& operator++(const LinkedList )

    Node* front; //front of a linked list
    Node* back;
    int size; //# of nodes in a linked list
};

#endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, that it should look like the following:

```
#ifndef NODE_H
#define NODE_H
class Node
{
public:
    Node(Node* n = NULL, int v =0)
    {
        // Where do you set prev?
        next = n;
        value = v;
    }

    Node * operator ++ (int)
    {
        return next;
    }

    Node * operator -- (int)
    {
        return prev;
    }

    Node* next;
    Node* prev; 
    int value;
};

#endif
```

Read further about operator overloading on the [C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/operator-overloading.html).

Comment: If my answer resolves your problem, please don't forget to accept it (click the "V" sign below the answer's vote count). It's generally a good habit to do so on the SO.

Comment: Will do in 4 minutes :)

Comment: Just a quick question. How do I call this in my LL class? Everything I try seems to crash my program

Comment: I would like it to point to the next node of the node i'm using. For example:   node *temp = cur++

Comment: You should be able to call it simply the same way you shown me here as long as `cur` is a `Node`. If it is a `Node *`, then you should call `Node * temp = (*cur)++`. I made a small change in the code (it seems, that postfix operator overload requires a dummy int parameter to make it different from a prefix ++ operator declaration)

Comment: Read further: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347661/implementing-a-c-postfix-increment-operator