# Why does (0 < 5 < 3) return true?

Tags: javascript, compare, operators, boolean-logic

I was playing around in jsfiddle.net and I'm curious as to why this returns true?

```
if(0 < 5 < 3) {
    alert("True");
}
```

So does this:

```
if(0 < 5 < 2) {
    alert("True");
}
```

But this doesn't:

```
if(0 < 5 < 1) {
    alert("True");
}
```

Is this quirk ever useful?

Comment: Do you know http://wtfjs.com/ ?

Comment: Ha! No I'd never seen that before.

Comment: Ah, the joys of implicit type conversions.

Comment: Ever useful? Possibly for obfuscation. :-)

Comment: Why? Also, *anything* is useful if you can only find the circumstances that require it. True, this one is less often required than many others, but there are times, few and far between though they may be, where it might be exactly the tool for the job.

Comment: [Language support for chained comparison operators (x < y < z)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4090845/995714)

Answer (score 453, accepted):

Order of operations causes `(0 < 5 < 3)` to be interpreted in javascript as `((0 < 5) < 3)` which produces `(true < 3)` and true is counted as 1, causing it to return true.

This is also why `(0 < 5 < 1)` returns false, `(0 < 5)` returns true, which is interpreted as `1`, resulting in `(1 < 1)`.

Comment: And because JavaScript is NOT Python. :-)

Comment: You answered while I was editing my question to add the `if(0 < 5 < 1) == false`. All is clear now, thanks :)

Comment: Exactly, Python is the only language I know of that treats this syntax as `((0 < 5) && (5 < 3))`, there are probably others but I don't know of them.

Comment: @Alan: Mathematica is another example.

Comment: And is neither Ruby... :P

Comment: IMHO JavaScript should raise TypeError when trying to compare boolean with number, because it makes no sense.

Answer (score 64):

My guess is because `0 < 5` is true, and `true < 3` gets cast to `1 < 3` which is true.

Comment: There's no casting here. A cast is an operator, which the programmer uses to *explicitly* check a type. This is *implicit* conversion from a boolean to an integer.

Comment: @erickson, really...do we NEED to be hung up on semantics here?

Comment: Don't worry about erickson. I misuses the word semantic too. :)

Comment: In any case the correct term is _coercion_. And yes, erickson is partially wrong with it's absolute certainty. A coercion is in any case a kind of cast also if usually (but it's just a convention) you use the word "cast" to express explicit type conversions. Type conversion == Type casting.

Comment: Sophists all the way... The reply is 'laconically' nice anyway ;)

Answer (score 22):

probably because `true` is assumed as `1` so

```
0 < 5 < 3  -->  true < 3 -->  1 < 3  --> true
```

Answer (score 18):

Because `true < 3`, because `true == 1`

Answer (score 11):

As to your question whether this quirk is ever useful: I suppose there could be some case where it would useful (if condensed code is what you are after), but relying on it will (most likely) severely reduce the understandability of your code.

It's kind of like using post/pre increment/decrement as a part of bigger expressions.  Can you determine what this code's result is at a glance?

```
int x = 5;
int result = ++x + x++ + --x;
```

*Note: with this code, you can sometimes even get different results depending on the language and compiler.*

It's a good idea to **make life easy for yourself and the next guy** who will read your code.  Clearly write out what you actually want to have happen rather then relying on side effects like the implicit conversion of booleans.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is `result` 18?

Comment: @MrMisterMan: I'm not certain about Javascript, but in Java and C# the evaluation is guaranteed to be left to right, and the result is indeed 18.  In some languages, such as C and C++, there is no guarantee it will be evaluated left to right, and you may end up with different results depending on the optimizations added by your compiler.

Answer (score 9):

The answer to the second part of the question, "is this quirk ever useful?" is perhaps no, as noted by a previous answer, if it is indeed a quirk of the language (Javascript) that true is cast to 1, but that the programmer does not in general view 1 and true  (and 0 and false) as the same thing.

If however you have a mental model of 1 being true and 0 being false, then it leads to all sorts of nice boolean techniques that are extremely useful, powerful, and direct. For example, you could increment a counter directly with the result of  A > 100, which would increment the counter if A is greater than 100. This technique might be viewed as a quirk or a trick in Java, but in an array or functional language may be idiomatic.

A classic example in the array language APL would be to count the number of items in an array that are (say) greater than 100:

```
+/A>100
```

Where if A is the 5 item array 107 22 256 110 3 then:

```
A>100
```

yields the 5 item boolean array:

1 0 1 1 0

and summing this boolean result:

```
+/1 0 1 1 0
```

yields the final answer:

3

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076078/check-if-at-least-2-out-of-3-booleans-is-true) is a perfect example of where this technique would be very useful, especially if the problem is generalized to determine if n out of m boolean values are true.

[Check if at least two out of three booleans are true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076078/check-if-at-least-2-out-of-3-booleans-is-true)

Answer (score 7):

That's easy.

```
(0 < 5 < 3)
```

Start with left to right so it evaluates the first 0 < 5. Is it true? Yes. Since TRUE=1, it evaluates 1 < 3. Since 1 is less than 3 so it's true.

Now with this

```
 (0 < 5 < 1)
```

Is 0 less than 5? Yes. So make it TRUE which also means 1. Now with that fact in mind, it evaluates to (1 < 1). Is 1 less than 1? No, therefore it's false. It has to be equal.

Answer (score 4):

is it evaluating 0<5 which would return 1 for true when 1<3 which is true?

C# want let you do this "Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'int'"

Comment: Sometimes I miss C#'s strictness in dynamic languages.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this a little while ago in Obj-C and was very puzzled by it. I got the results I wanted by doing something like this:

```
if(0 < 5  && 5 < 3) {
alert("True");}
```

Which of course is false so you wouldn't get that "true" alert.
Glad I read this, I now know why.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to python, CoffeeScript is another language that supports chained comparisons, thus `3 < x < 10` would be converted to `(3 < x && x < 10)` in vanilla JS

Answer (score 3):

```
0 < 5 < 3 
==> ( ( 0 < 5 ) < 3 )
==> true < 3
==> 1 < 3
==> true
```

Answer (score 1):

A boolean operand when operated over a math operator returns a number.
to check this we do

```
true + 1  which gives you 2.
```

So `0 < 5`, the returned boolean(true) operated with math operator(<) will return a number. So it boils to 1<3 which returns `true`

Answer (score 1):

because 0 is less then 5 then that returns true, and by default true is anything including and can be evaluated to 1 which is still less than 3 which again returns true

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same thing.

code:

```js
// Case 1
console.log(1 < 2 < 3); // true
// Case 2
console.log(3 > 2 > 1); // false
```

In JavaScript, both Case 1 and Case 2 involve chaining comparison operators, and the behavior might seem counterintuitive due to how JavaScript handles them based on operator precedence and associativity.

1. **Case 1: `console.log(1 < 2 < 3); // true`**

   - This evaluates as `(1 < 2) < 3`.
   - Firstly, `1 < 2` is true (`true` in JavaScript can be implicitly converted to `1` in numeric comparisons).
   - Then, `true` when compared to `3` is coerced into numeric values, resulting in `1 < 3`, which is true.
   - Thus, the final output is `true`.
2. **Case 2: `console.log(3 > 2 > 1); // false`**

   - This evaluates as `(3 > 2) > 1`.
   - Firstly, `3 > 2` is true (`true`).
   - Then, `true` when compared to `1` is coerced into numeric values, resulting in `1 > 1`, which is false.
   - Therefore, the final output is `false`.

This behavior can be confusing due to JavaScript's implicit type coercion and left-to-right associativity of comparison operators, which can lead to unexpected results when chaining these operations together.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your answer. Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your answer with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Happy coding!

Comment: @AztecCodes here is the updated and explained answer. Happy coding!

Answer (score -1):

try phrasing your results as Number()

```
if(Number(0) < Number(5) < Number(3)) {
    alert("True");
}
```

or try this:

```
if(Number(0) < Number(5) && Number(5) < Number(3)) {
    alert("True");
}
```

I googled this because I was getting `(3 >= 20) //returning true` and I guess javascript was trying to check `3` as a boolean because I was getting this value from the `elm.getAttribute();` function which `console.log();` was printing in String form.