# How come this is true?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does (0 < 5 <3) return true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089284/why-does-0-5-3-return-true)

How come this is true?:

`console.log(100 < 210 < 200); // outputs true`

Comment: see: [http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92074/what-can-i-do-when-getting-it-does-not-meet-our-quality-standards]

Answer (score 3):

That's equivalent to:

```
console.log((100 < 210) < 200);
```

which is equivalent to:

```
console.log(true < 200);
```

And this evaluates to `true` because when using operators like `<`, `true` is treated as if it were a `1`

Consequently, the following will evaluate to `false`:

```
console.log(true < 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

`100 < 210 < 200` is equivalent to `(100 < 210) < 200` which is `true < 200` which is `1 < 200` which is `true`.

That last bit (`true` becoming `1`) may be a bit surprising. It's the result of how JavaScript does relational operations ([Section 11.8.5](http://es5.github.com/#x11.8.5) of the spec), which says amongst other things that if the relation is between a non-number (other than `null` or `undefined`) and a number, you convert the non-number to a number, and the conversion of `true` to a number results in `1` ([Section 9.3](http://es5.github.com/#x9.3) of the spec.)