# JavaScript If-else range check in opposite not working

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements

Can anyone please explain the logic behind this code?

```
function getGrade(score) {
    let grade;
    if (20 < score <= 30) {
      grade = "A";
    } else if (10 < score <= 20) {
      grade = "B";
    } else if (0 < score <= 10) {
      grade = "C";
    }
    return grade;
  }

  console.log(getGrade(15));    //'A'
  console.log(getGrade(4));     //'A'
  console.log(getGrade(20));    //'A'
```

It is working fine with using `&&` operator in `if-else` or using opposite as: `30>= score > 25`. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What specifically don't you understand?

Comment: why the first 'if condition' is giving 'true' all the time?

Comment: I think it's because in JS `x < y < z` is not correct. It should be `x < y && y < z`

Comment: `20 < score` is either `true` or `false`. When compared to a number, `true` is converted to `1` and `false` is converted to `0` and both `0 <= 30` and `1 <= 30` are always true, hence the comparison is always true.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if a value is within a range of numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6454198/check-if-a-value-is-within-a-range-of-numbers)

Comment: but if I go with your logic, and use ```30> score >= 25```, then it will be ```30> score```, either ***true*** or ***false***. i.e. ```1``` or ```0``` and ```0 >= 25``` and ```1 >= 25``` will always be ```false```. Don't you think? @Ivar

Comment: @MitanshuKumar Seems like that is the case: https://jsfiddle.net/p7hwyn8x/

Comment: Thank you @Ivar. You are right. If we use ```x < y < z```, it will always be true, and if ```x > y > z``` it will always be false. _(!) x,y,z != 0 or 1_. Conclusively, we should always use ```x < y && y < z``` in JS.

Comment: [Duplicate](https://google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+20+<+score+<%3D+30+not+working) of [Why does (0 < 5 < 3) return true?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4089284/4642212).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `20 < score <= 30` evaluated to true all the time because of how multiple operators work when using them in Javascript, see more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

What is happening is that first is `20 < score` evaluated, and this is either `true` (1) or `false` (0). This value is then compared if it is less than or equal to 30. As the value is always either 1 or 0, this is always less than 30, so the whole expression as a whole is always true.

Try these lines yourself to see how it works. :)

```
score = 10;
b = 20 < score; // false
c = b <= 30; // always outputs true

// Also try
d = true <= 30; // true
e = false <= 30; // true
```

What you should do here, is as you write, to use &&-operators instead:

```
if (20 < score && score <= 30) {
    grade = "A";
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Olov. I was bit confused, as in other languages ```x<y<z``` or ```x>y>z``` works fine. In JS, we should use ```&&``` operator in-between.