# Why console.log(10 < 14 < 50) is true but console.log(10 > 7 > 2) is false?

Tags: javascript

Why console.log(10 < 14 < 50) is true but console.log(10 > 7 > 2) is false?
why does first give true and second gives false

Comment: Because `10 < 14 < 50` = `1 < 50` while `10 > 7 > 2` = `1 > 2`

Comment: [Operator Precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#table) is a good resource to be familiar with

Comment: Alternative duplicate: [Why does (0 < 5 < 3) return true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089284/why-does-0-5-3-return-true?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 4):

It works that way:

First it calculate the left side `(10 < 14)` => it returns `True`, which is also `1`.

Then it calculates the right side: `(True < 50)` which is `(1 < 50)` and this is also `True`.

On the other side, `(10 > 7)` => `True` = `1`, but `(True > 2)` which is `(1 > 2)` is `False`.

If you'll try: `console.log(10 < 14 == 1)`
you will see that it's also `True`.

Answer (score 2):

This is not how you would check an interval in JS.

Your code would be interpreted from left to right according to [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence). The [comparison operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators#relational_operators) are *binary* operators, they take a left-hand expression and a right-hand expression

```js
10 < 15 < 50
// To
true < 50 
// To
1 < 50

// And 
10 > 7 > 2
// To
true > 2 
// To
1 > 2
```

You should do:

```js
console.log(14 < 10 && 14 <50)
//
console.log(7 < 10 && 7 > 2)
```