# My Javascript code always returns 10 or 11 and never returns the other random numbers which have not been specified in the if condition

Tags: javascript

**This is my Javascript code:**

```js
function getRandomCard(){
        randomCard = Math.floor(Math.random()*13)+1
    
        if (randomCard === 1){
            return 11
        }
        
        else if (11 <= randomCard <= 13){
            return 10   
        }
    
        else{
            return randomCard
        }
    }
    
 console.log(getRandomCard())
```

I have linked it to an HTML file with a button to call this function on getting clicked. Every time it is, it only returns 10 or 11. What could be wrong with my code?

Comment: `11 <= randomCard <= 13` doesn't work in JavaScript, use `11 <= randomCard && randomCard <= 13`

Comment: @NickstandswithUkraine It [works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089284/why-does-0-5-3-return-true) BUT not in a way one would expect. OP needs to use the `&&` operator like you suggested.

Comment: @Yousaf That depends on your definition of work :p, but yes, I'm aware, I was the one that voted to close.

Comment: @NickstandswithUkraine Your comment suggested that `11 <= randomCard <= 13` is syntactically wrong. Anyways, I didn't notice that you had voted to close the question.

Comment: @Yousaf What is actually happening in my code then? If you could please let me know.

Comment: `11 <= randomCard <= 13` - this expression is evaluated from left to right. FIrst `11 <= randomCard` is evaluated. It will evaluate to a boolean value (either true or false).  So the expression is reduced to `true <= 13` or `false <= 13`. As you are comparing boolean value with a number, boolean value is converted into a number (true -> 1, false -> 0). At the end you are comparing either `1 <= 13` or `0 <= 13` which evaluates to true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure maybe your if condition is wrong..

```js
function getRandomCard(){
        randomCard = Math.floor(Math.random()*13)+1
    
        if (randomCard === 1){
            return 11
        }
        
        else if (11 <= randomCard && randomCard <= 13){
            return 10   
        }
    
        else{
            return randomCard
        }
    }
    
 console.log(getRandomCard())
```