# What does "?" and ":" do in boolean statements?

Tags: java, boolean, operators, boolean-expression

I think this question is a general programming question,
but let's assume I'm asking this for Java.

what does the following statement do ?

```
return a ? (b || c) : (b && c);
```

I have seen the syntax with `?`'s and `:`'s in many topics at SO, this particular one I found in [Check if at least two out of three booleans are true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076078/check-if-at-least-two-out-of-three-booleans-are-true)

But I don't know what they mean, so how to use them, and I believe it's something very useful for me.

Thanks !

Comment: It's a short cut `if-else` statement

Comment: `? :` does the same thing returning `boolean` values as it does with any other type.

Comment: So why does everyone here think this is a duplicate of that question? That question has little to do with this one.

Comment: @Makoto Should have been marked as a duplicate of [What is the Java ?: operator called and what does it do?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/798545/479863) but I don't think it is worth reopening just so that it can be closed as a duplicate of a different question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's the conditional operator.  It means something like:

```
condition ? value-if-true : value-if-false;
```

So in your case, it returns `b || c` if `a` is true, and `b && c` if `a` is false.

Comment: Thank you so much! I cannot believe I couldn't find such a simple thing in google, and I was right, it saves at least 4 lines of code for me :)

Comment: It's technically called the conditional operator - and it happens to be *a* ternary operator (takes three arguments).

Comment: And, are ternary operators valid for common languages like C,PHP,JavaScript etc? I will choose your answer in 10 minutes.

Comment: Yes, as far as I know it originated in C.

Comment: Wikipedia says it comes from CPL.  And they call it the ternary operator, too.  I don't know where to look up an official name.  Is there a java spec out there somewhere?  C definitely calls it the conditional operator.

Comment: @CarlNorum Is it possible to do two things if condition is true or false with `ternary ops`? for eg. `condition ? do this and do that : do something else and something even more`

Comment: I don't know enough java to know if it has a comma operator.  Yes, you can probably do more than one thing, though.  Why not just use `if`/`else` in that case?

Answer (score 3):

This is known as a ternary statement; it's shorthand for an if-else block - you can google that for more info.

Your example is equivalent to

```
if (a) {
   return (b || c);
} else {
   return (b && c);
}
```

Comment: Yes, I was looking for this for days. I'm always trying to simplify my code and this operator turns these 5 lines to 1 line. I love it ! Thanks.

Comment: @user223150 Less lines does not mean simpler code, really. The if/else-clause is simpler and more readable if you ask me. Putting ternary statements in ternary statements can become a messy ordeal.

Answer (score 2):

```
condition ? first statement : second statement
```

if condition is true then first statement is executed otherwise the second statement

Comment: executed? so can I also write `condition ? function1() : function2();` ?

Answer (score 0):

It's the ternary operator, the whole statement expands to something more like this:

```
if a == true then
  if b == true or c == true then
    return true
else 
  if b == true and c == true then
    return true
```

As your link says a much more elegant way to check if at least 2 out of three booleans are true when applied in this way!

Answer (score 0):

its an conditional operator... jst like if and else....

e.g----

```
a<b ? 4 :5      where a= 2 and b=5
```

as a is less then b....    then this operator will return 4...   else it return 5....

in short...   if your condition i.e   statement before ? is correct then it returns 1st value.. i.e statement before colon....  else it returns 2nd value......

Answer (score 0):

According to your code,
    return a ? (b || c) : (b && c);

Result will be like this :

if a == true , then result = b || c
     otherwise result = b && c

its a ternary operator & used in most of the languages C,C++, java, Javascript