# "var &= expr" does not behave like "var = var && expr"

Tags: java, compilation

I'm just curious. I would like to know if there is a specific reason why the expression

```
var &= expr
```

does not behave the same way as

```
var = var && expr.
```

It looks like the expression in the first one is being executed regardless of a false value on var.

I'm using Java 6, FYI. This code:

```
public class Test
{
    protected static String getString()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        String string = getString();
        boolean test = (string != null);
        test = test && (string.length() > 0);
        System.out.println("First test passed");
        test &= (string.length() > 0);
        System.out.println("Second test passed");
    }
}
```

Gives me:

```
First test passed
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Test.main(Test.java:14)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

Comment: Ref. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7101992/why-do-we-usually-use-not-what-is-the-difference , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9264897/reason-for-the-exsistance-of-non-short-circuit-logical-operators , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014535/vs-and-vs

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`&` does not behave like `&&`<sup>1,2</sup>

`&` is an *eager* bitwise/boolean-And.

`&&` is a [*short-circuiting*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) logical-And.

---

<sup>1</sup> The line with `&=` is equivalent to `test = test & (string.length() > 0)`, which would also fail.

<sup>2</sup> See [Why do we usually use `||` not `|`, what is the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7101992/why-do-we-usually-use-not-what-is-the-difference) - the answers also cover the use of `&&` and `&`.

Answer (score 3):

> It looks like the expression in the first one is being executed regardless of a false value on var.

That's because the second expression uses short-circuit evaluation, while the first expression does not.

Answer (score 2):

They're not the same because `&` is a bitwise operator and `&&` is a logical operator on booleans.

`var &= expr` is equivalent to `var = var & expr`, not `var = var && expr`.

Answer (score 0):

In your case

```
test = test && (string.length() > 0); // test = false that why strings.length not evaluated

test &= (string.length() > 0); //calling length on null object that why NPE
```

Answer (score -1):

`&` is bitwise AND

`&&` is logical AND.

`true && true = true`..

`&` works on numbers, `&&` works on boolean expressions.

`0xFE & 0xFF` results in `0xFE`.

Answer (score -1):

```
var &= expr
```

is equivalent to

```
var = var & expr
```

In other words it does a *bitwise* or

```
var = var && expr
```

does a logical or of var and expr

Comment: Although the answer is right, you still miss the point of short circuit. & works very well with booleans.