# While java provides non short-circuit version of logical operators (like logical |, &), when are these required?

Tags: java, short-circuiting

I see that java (and many other languages like C# and VB) provide short-circuit and non short-circuit versions of logical "**and**" and "**or**" operators.
Where as C/C++ do not provide for **non** short-circuit versions.

When are these **non** short-circuit versions required? And if one can do without them why have these other languages provided for it?

Comment: Please provide an example code of what you are talking about.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9264897/reason-for-the-exsistance-of-non-short-circuit-logical-operators

Comment: Actually, C and C++ do provide the operators your're talking about (that's where most of the other languages got them from). It's not really useful or correct to think of them as eager boolean logic operators though.

Comment: I would say, as per *my* code guidelines, *never* use `&` and `|` for logical conditions, but rather move the side-effects *out* of the expression ..

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the cases in which it is better to use unconditional AND (& instead of &&)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11411907/what-are-the-cases-in-which-it-is-better-to-use-unconditional-and-instead-of)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example, you might have a situation where your conditionals are calculated by two methods:

```
if (methodA() && methodB())
```

Now if you absolutely require that both methods be ran at this point (perhaps they do something else relevant, like mark down that they have been evaluated), then you should not short-circuit the call:

```
if (methodA() & methodB())
```

This guarantees the same result, but it also guarantees that both methods will run. In general it's almost never used in practice from what I've seen, and I would possibly argue that it's even bad practice.

As to the question of WHY is this functionality in some languages and not others - that's simply a question for the language designers. At best we could guess here what their intention was.

Comment: You mean then you should _not_.

Comment: What do you mean? Did I miss a word somewhere?

Comment: Yeah, and I put it in instead of making a nonspecific comment.

Comment: I see, don't know how I missed it even after proof reading following @Keppil's comment. Thanks for the edit.

Comment: Because it's nearly impossible to proofread your own writing, since you already knew what you meant. ;-)

Comment: So you mean that while some languages provide for a non short-circuit version of these operator and they have a valid case when they could be used, it is not a good maintainable code to rather use them. The code should rather work around to use a short circuited version of the operator and call these methods prior to that short circuited if statement – so that the programmer intention is made explicitly clear.
Just that some languages provide for writing such a code that can use these non short-circuited versions instead.

Comment: @John Yes, essentially if you require these two methods to run, then run them and assign their return value to some temporary flags. Then, when it's time to compare, just compare the flags themselves. This eliminates the need for non-short-circuit evaluation. If you have no other question you can mark this answer as accepted by clicking the check mark under my answer score.