# Ruby TrueClass single pipe

Tags: ruby

From documentation: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/TrueClass.html#method-i-7C

```
true |  puts("or")
true || puts("logical or")

# produces:

or
```

- Could you explain when "single pipe" is useful?
- What's the difference?

(only in `TrueClass` context (not `Array` or `Fixnum` context )

Comment: `true || puts("logical or")` will give you `true`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is useful when you do not need eager evaluation of **or** statement.

For example, if you have some methods, that do something useful and returns `true`/`false` as a result, and have another method that should be called only if any of those methods returns `true`, it is useful to use `|`:

```
def action1
  # do something, returns true/false
end

def action2
  # do something, returns true/false
end

def result_action
  # do something 
end

result_action if action1 | action2
```

If you use logical `||` instead then if `action1` returns true, `action2` will not be called (`result_action` will be invoked though)

Comment: Absolutely. `puts` always returns `nil`, so both sides of `a || b` were invoked in your code @Mugur'Bud'Chirica

Answer (score 8):

It is hard to tell why `TrueClass` has a [`#|` method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/TrueClass.html#method-i-7C) defined.

The fact that it is a *method* does mean that both of its "operands" get evaluated and then combined, which is why the string `"or"` was output. The double pipe is a special construct: it will not evaluate the second operand if the first was truthy. Therefore, as a way to do boolean computations, the single pipe looks useless.

Now, the operator makes a lot more sense on [`Fixnum`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Fixnum.html#method-i-7C): it performs the same bitwise OR as seen in C, Java, etc.

For example:

```
>> 133|243
=> 247
```

Now Java, for some reason, overloaded `|` on booleans to be a non-short circuit operator. Perhaps Ruby is doing a "me too"? Doesn't seem likely that Ruby would want to copy Java here.

It's more likely the case that because

```
true | e
```

evaluates to

```
e
```

for any e, Ruby is allowing you to chain together a bunch of truthy expressions. Perhaps

```
true | e1 | e2 | e3 | e4
```

looks cooler than

```
e1
e2
e3
e4
true
```

or even

```
e1; e2; e3; e4; true
```

Another possibility might be that it allows you to chain together boolean-producing expressions with side-effects.

```
f(x1) | f(x2) | f(x3) | f(x4)
```

and return whether or not any of the functions produced `true`. Here's a contrived example:

```
>> def f(x);puts x;return x==2;end
=> :f
>> f(1) || f(2) || f(3) || f(4)
1
2
=> true
>> f(1) | f(2) | f(3) | f(4)
1
2
3
4
=> true
```

Of course, this is still just a lame attempt because you get the same effect with:

```
>> [f(1),f(2),f(3),f(4)].any?
1
2
3
4
=> true
```

I suspect, but am not 100% sure, that the operator is included for some kind of "completeness" in the algebraic sense. Boolean algebra has AND or OR, and the `||` isn't really a method in the classic sense of having eager evaluation semantics. So maybe it was thrown in because of that reason, and, if any programmer happens to find a use for it, then wonderful. But I've never seen, in many years of programming, any *pragmatic* reason for not short-circuiting.

I would in fact argue that if someone were to write code that *depended* on the evaluation of the second argument in a boolean context (i.e., using `#|`), that such code would be confusing --- and certainly not referentially transparent, as it would rely on side effects --- and should therefore be rewritten.

Comment: Mostly `#|` is a method, but `||` is an operator.

Comment: Thanks you. But why not to write: `true && e1 && e2 && e3 && e4` ?

Comment: You know, this is a _really_ good question. I'm STILL trying to figure it out myself. When I come up with something, I will add it to the answer. There are so many ways to do things. I suspect you can use this in an DSL somewhere, _somehow_, because, as you suspect, it appears to be completely useless as a boolean operator!

Comment: This example I've tried `a |= puts 'hi' ; puts a ; #=> hi false` overkilled me. Where it can be useful, i still can not imagine ;) Thanks for answers. My vote up :)

Comment: Just noticed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9264897/reason-for-the-exsistance-of-non-short-circuit-logical-operators but again, I think these cases are a little convoluted and should be rewritten.

Comment: Java was first publicly released in 1995, Ruby was designed in 1993, so I really doubt there's any "me-tooing" going on. AFAIK, the only thing Ruby ever took from the Java community are Refinements in Ruby 2.0, which are (very) loosely based on [Classboxes](http://scg.unibe.ch/research/classboxes).

Comment: It was supposed to be tongue-in-cheek, along the lines of people criticizing [Pascal for using the non-C `:=` despite the fact C wasn't invented yet](http://james-iry.blogspot.com/2009/05/brief-incomplete-and-mostly-wrong.html).