# in java are Logical Xor and Bitwise Xor share same ^

Tags: java

in java are Logical Xor and Bitwise Xor share same ^

I tried to looked at my java book and seems so.
So strange?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Effect of a Bitwise Operator on a Boolean in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1724205/effect-of-a-bitwise-operator-on-a-boolean-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's both, depending on the operands.

[JLS 15.22.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22.1):

> When both operands of an operator &, ^, or | are of a type that is convertible (§5.1.8) to a primitive integral type ...

or in other words, two integral operands result in a bitwise XOR.

```
    0  1

0   0  1
1   1  0
```

or [JLS 15.22.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22.2):

> When both operands of a &, ^, or | operator are of type boolean or Boolean, then the type of the bitwise operator expression is boolean.

```
        false   true

false   false    true
 true    true   false
```

It isn't at all strange for operators to perform different functions depending upon operands - consider addition versus string concatenation. `2 + 2` and `"Hello " + "world!"` are clearly two different kinds of operations.