# && logical operator functioning

Tags: java, operators

```
class BoolArray  {
    boolean [] b = new boolean[3];

    int count = 0;

    void set(int i) 
    {
        b[i] = true;
        ++count;
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) 
    {
        BoolArray ba = new BoolArray();
        ba.set(0);
        ba.set(2);
        ba.test();
    }

    void test() 
    {
        if ( b[0] && b[1] | b[2] )
           count++;
        if ( b[1] && b[(++count - 2)] )
           count += 7;
        System.out.println("count = " + count);
    }
}
```

in all these scenarios,

```
if ( b[0] && b[1] | b[2] )

if ( b[1] && b[0] || b[2] )

if ( b[1] && b[0] || b[2] )
```

Why the short circuit logic of '&&' not working as the code is reaching inside the if block?

Please explain also in what order logical operators are executed.

Comment: *"why the short circuit logic of '&&' not working"* - I can guarantee you it is working as expected. The actual expectation may differ from *your* expectation though. What do you expect to happen instead of what is happening?

Comment: As your code (and the first result on google) shows, the order is first && then ||. Shortcut does not change the outcome of boolean logic.

Comment: What do you expect your code to do? What does your code actually do? i.e. What output do you expect and what output do you get? Your code is a lot more complex than it needs to be to demonstrate your problem - can you reduce your code down to a [mcve]?

Comment: Related: [Effect of a Bitwise Operator on a Boolean in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18386156) (unless that `|` was supposed to be `||`)

Comment: Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly. And you want us to spend our time to help you with your problem so you please react to the feedback you get here.

Answer (score 0):

> Why the short circuit logic of '&&' not working as the code is
>   reaching inside the if block?

The short circuit logic is working just fine.  `count` is 3 before you get to the second `if` statement, and it correctly doesn't process the `++count` and leaves it at 3.

> Please explain also in what order logical operators are executed.

[The order is](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html):

bitwise AND     &
bitwise exclusive OR    ^
bitwise inclusive OR    |
logical AND     &&
logical OR  ||